# In Ember, how to add a click handler to a dynamically generated HTML in Ember

Tags: ember.js

I have a function in an Ember library that generates html.

```
    getHTMLPreview: function(preview){
      var article_div ="<div class='onebox'>"
      + "<a href='"+preview.url+"'</a>"
      + "<article class='onebox-body'><div class='remove-preview'></div>" 
      + ( preview.img  !== "" ?  "<img src='"+preview.img+"' class='thumbnail'/>"  : "")
      + "<h3><a href='"+preview.url+"'>"+preview.title+"</a>"
      + "</h3>"
      + "<p>"+preview.description+"</p>"
      + "</article>"
      + "<div style='clear:both'></div></div>"
    ;
    return article_div;
}
```

I want to add a click handler on $(".remove-preview") and do something when that div is clicked. 
getHTMLPreview is called on the success of an ajax function in the same library.

Comment: Why are you manually generating the html instead of using ember views?

Answer (score 0):

If you are building your html outside of ember, you might as well hook up your event handling outside of ember.  There is no gain in hacking in the action control from ember to it.  If you need to interact with ember at some point, you will need to access the private container to gain access to a controller/route you want access too.

```
var fooController = App.__container__.lookup('controller:foo');
```